# Azure Could Computing high availoability vs NEO4J high availability?

Tags: neo4j

We are planning to use Azure Storage in a virtual Environment. Azure already offers very high availability, load balancing and replication of data around the world. If we install NEO4j Graph (using Java embedded) in a IIS server with high availability. Do we still need to design and use the NEO4j high availability architecture?

We still need the backup option of NEO4J (enterprise license for sure) but it would be nice not to get in the business of load balancing and replication. Azure Cloud does a very good job already. Thank you!

Best,

George Moon

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is probably yes.

Windows Azure provide you infrastructure that allow you to build high availability system, it won't make any system high available by magic.

As NEO4J is state-full, each node (with only one node Azure don't give you any SLA, you instance will be down) will need to share some state and the way to do it will be dependent on how NEO4J is working.  So you will need to rely on NEO4J mechanism to do it.

I don't know how NEO4J is working but you won't be able to skip designing an high available architecture around NEO4J using Windows Azure infra.

Cloud may be a magic buzz word that can make things append on management level, but when we are on hard real world level Harry magic wand doesn't exist.